# Surrounding Areas SQL

Tags: sql, vbscript, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get a query to work which returns a list of locId's from the database when fed a long and a lat.

**Here's the sql:**

eg: lat = "-37.8333300" : lon = "145.000000" : radius = (5 * 0.621371192) ^ 2

```
SELECT locId,longitude,latitude FROM tbliplocations WHERE (69.1*([longitude]- "&lon&") * cos("&lat&"/57.3))^2 + (69.1*([latitude]- "&lat&"))^2 < "&radius
```

**Here's the error I receive:**

> The data types float and int are incompatible in the '^' operator.

I'm unsure of a workaround, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Answer:**

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SELECT city FROM tbliplocationsnew WHERE POWER((69.1*([longitude]- "&lon&") * cos("&lat&"/57.3)),2) + POWER((69.1*([latitude]- "&lat&")),2)  < "&radius
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what database you use, but I think that "^2" in SQL does not mean "squared" like in maths. You should use a math "power" function, like POWER(number,2) in SQL Server (since you use VB maybe you use SQL Server ?)

Comment: There's at least an exception : PostgreSQL treats ^ like the power function it seems (just installed one and checked, after reading some page on the web about arithmetic operator in PostgreSQL: select 10 ^2 returns 100). But not MySQL. Got to check SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks Huelbois, that did the trick! Updated question with answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two of the same data type it's saying.  SQL thinks "5" is an int.  So, you should be able to trick it into treating it as a float, by putting "5.0" instead.